# Creating multiparticle states from vacuum in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, identical-particles

In creating multiparticle states from the vacuum we apply the creation operators,
\begin{align}
&|p_1,s_1\rangle=a^{\dagger}_{p_1,s_1}|0\rangle,\\
&|p_1,s_1;p_2,s_2\rangle=a^{\dagger}_{p_1,s_1}a^{\dagger}_{p_2,s_2}|0\rangle,\\
& ...\quad ...\quad ...\quad ...\quad ...\quad ... \\
&|p_1,s_1;p_2,s_2;...\,\,...;p_n,s_n\rangle=a^{\dagger}_{p_1,s_1}a^{\dagger}_{p_2,s_2}...\,...\, ...a^{\dagger}_{p_n,s_n}|0\rangle
 \qquad \qquad \text{etc.}
\end{align}

for particles having momentum $p$ and spin $s$. Some authors also include  combinatorial prefactors like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2!}}$, ... $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}$ on the r.h.s. My question is that is it just a convention, to be compensated later by some other similar normalization prefactor, e.g. in the definition of inner product, amplitude, etc? Or does it have a concrete physical reason, in order to incorporate the indistinguishability of fermions/bosons, since the ordering of the creation-operators is ambiguous up to a sign?

Comment: It is just a convention. Different authors prefer different conventions.

Comment: Note that since states are physically distinguishable only up to a phase, there can be no physical reason for adding prefactors like this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Can you please highlight where exactly the combinatorial pre-factor for indistinguishability is accounted for in QFT if the states are defined without them?

Comment: hint: compute norm.